# JavaScript: mouse events stop firing while the mouse is down

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I have encountered a situation where certain mouse events stops firing while the user is dragging with the mouse.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qbd501mz/1/) of the issue.

UPDATE: You can find [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1pk7jev4/) a much simpler jsFiddle which also displays the issue.

**The context**
I am creating a tool to crop images. To do this, I create a set of `<div>` elements over an image, and the user will be able to drag the corners and the edges of the parent `<div>` by dragging one of the child `<div>`s.

**The details**
On `mousedown`, I add two event listeners to the document body:

- a `mousemove` event listener, to fire constantly
- a `mouseup` event listener, to fire once and remove the `mousemove` listener when the user stops dragging the mouse

**The result**
This always works perfectly the first time you drag a corner or an edge. However, the second time you drag the same corner or edge, the `mousemove` event fires between 1 and 6 times (in my experience) and then stops. The `mouseup` event is not fired when you release the mouse, but from that moment on, the `mousemove` events resume, and a subsequent click-and-release will generate a `mouseup` event.

**Investigation**
In Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that the event listeners are present by entering `getEventListeners(document.body)` into the console, or by checking in the Event Listeners pane of the Elements tab, for the `body` element.

Any help in understanding why this is occurring, and in how to resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

---

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Crop Image</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="crop">
  <div class="topLeft"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="topRight"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="bottomRight"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <div class="bottomLeft"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
<pre id="feedback"></pre>
  <script src="js/crop.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
div#crop {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div#crop div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#crop .top,
div#crop .bottom {
  left: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

div#crop .left,
div#crop .right {
  top: 20px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

div#crop .topRight,
div#crop .right,
div#crop .bottomRight {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

div#crop .bottomLeft,
div#crop .bottom,
div#crop .bottomRight {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

pre#feedback {
  position: fixed;
  top:40px;
  left:40px
}
```

JavaScript

```
"use strict"

let cropType
  , counter
let div = document.getElementById("crop")
let feedback = document.getElementById("feedback")

document.body.onmousemove = log
div.addEventListener("mousedown", startResizeImage, false)

function startResizeImage(event) {
  log("startResize")
  cropType = event.target.className
  counter = 0

  document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", resizeImage, false)
  document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", stopResizeImage, {once: true})
}

function resizeImage(event) {
  log ("drag (" + ++counter + ") " + cropType)
}

function stopResizeImage() {
  log("stopResize")
  document.body.removeEventListener("mousemove", resizeImage, false)
}

function log(data) {
  data = data.type || data
  let text = data+": "+event.clientX+", "+event.clientY
  let lines = feedback.innerHTML.split("<br>")

  if (data === "mousemove") {
    text = text + "\n" + lines.pop() 
  } else {
    text = lines.shift() + "\n" + text
  }

  feedback.innerText = text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second drag operation was failing was because the browser used the first drag-and-release to create a selection, whose `anchorNode` was the `<div>` that was clicked. The second drag then tried to move this selection. The clue that revealed this was that the cursor changed to a `move` closed hand, almost immediately after the second drag began.

The solution is to use CSS to prevent the draggable `<div>`s from being selected:

```
div#crop {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;          /* Likely future */
}
```

The irony is that, in the past when I have created a drag feature, I have always disabled selection, for cosmetic reasons. I had not realized that it was a key factor for the success of the operation.